# Multiple or One Project for single team in Fogbugz?

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-on-demand

We've been using Fogbugz for a few months now, and have about 6 projects (aside from the default Inbox project for incoming mail).

We work in week-long sprints, so we have set up global milestones for each week to prevent having to enter them multiple times (for each project).

The iteration planner doesn't support planning for multiple projects simultaneously.

As we are sprint planning in a global fashion (across all the projects at once), would having one project with multiple areas be a better fit for this workflow/planning?

Does this go against a design principle of Fogbugz, or will it make some features not work correctly?

The documentation on Projects and Areas doesn't mention pros and cons of one over the other.

Comment: I've used Fogbugz for the past year and a half, and I've only used it as a time tracker. That said,  you can track multiple projects, I found that documentation here: http://help.fogcreek.com/7451/projects-and-areas and Iteration Planner docs here: http://help.fogcreek.com/10547/planning-sprints-with-the-iteration-planner

Comment: @NathanielFlick: I've reviewed those, but the Projects and Areas page doesn't really touch on pros and cons of multiple projects instead of multiple areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lou @ Fog Creek replied:

> I would say that, instead of pros and cons, there's an idea of grouping for the purposes of planning. Planning units should get their own projects, and any natural subdivisions within that unit most likely merit an Area. The main advantages of Areas is being able to have different primary contacts for workflows and organization.

So it seems the overall design concept of Projects is something that is individually planned, and in this situation, all our activity fits into one Project.